# Is an 'On Networks' N300MA Wifi Adapter compatible?

Tags: networking, wifi

Does anyone know whether it is possible to use an 'On Networks' N300MA (N300MA-199WWS) wifi adapter with a Raspberry Pi - model B?

http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing-accessories/networking/wireless-cards-adaptors/on-networks-n300ma-199wws-n300-wireless-usb-micro-adapter-21248451-pdt.html

`lsusb` reports that it is manufactured by NetGear (rebranded?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lsusb reports that it is manufactured by NetGear (rebranded?)

That's the actual wifi chip.  I don't think this is considered "rebranding", it's just how the tiers of the electronics industry work; there are probably 20 times as many companies distributing wifi adapters as actually manufacturing wifi chips.  They design an adapter and choose the components, they get someone to manufacture it, they package it, and they sell it wholesale.  That's how the pi happens too -- none of the chips on that board are made by the Raspberry Pi Foundation, nor (presumably) are they unique to it.

You'll need the exact `ID xxxx:xxxx` from the `lsusb` output; these chip ids are used to select the kernel driver.  Some effort has been made to include those on the [elinux RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters page](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).  If the kernel doesn't load a driver for it automatically though, chances are you are out of luck.

Comment: You can check the ID [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB) as well...

Comment: Yeah [the elinux list](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) seems to be the best place to look, and this Wifi Adapter isn't supported